# UI Testing ways to utilise app switcher option

Tags: xcode-ui-testing

Can't find an option to move app to app-switcher and bring it back to active without launching the app during UITesting

I've found that there's an option in **Assistive launch** for app-switcher in iPhone, which resides in **Device** option. Hence, I hope there might be an option in UITesting too.

I found this [background and re-launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653384/sending-app-to-background-and-re-launching-it-from-recents-in-xctest), but I would like to open my app without relaunching for my test cases.

I expect to directly move to app-switcher and go back to my app.

Comment: [app.activate()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/2873317-activate) I could use this to bring my app to active state without re-launching. Though is there any way to view the app in app switcher ?